# AlignmentSpan not working for RadioButton text

Tags: android

I'm trying to align to the right a portion of a `RadioButton` text using the `AlignmentSpan` class. However it is not working because the text is not aligned as expected.

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

builder.append(option.getLabel());

int start = builder.length() + 1;

builder.append(" ");
builder.append(price);
builder.append("€");

int end = builder.length();

builder.setSpan(new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE), start, end,
        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

final StyleSpan bss = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD);

builder.setSpan(bss, start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

As you can see from the code I also apply a `StyleSpan` which works properly.

N.B `RadioButton` has `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

Answer (score 2):

Random advice, might work or not, but... Did you try injecting Unicode control characters in the string?
(improperly) Using characters such as U+200E, U+200F, U+202A...U+202E you can convince the text renderer that they are parts of RTL mixed with LTR. Not sure if that helps or not, you might need to have stuff in separated paragraphs anyway, but that's the only thing I could think of right now.

Answer (score 2):

Try this once `android:layout_width="_wrap_content"`.

and try this and tell me result....

```
final StyleSpan bss = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD);

builder.setSpan(bss, start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    int end = builder.length();

builder.setSpan(new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE), start, end,
        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

If i m not wrong You are **overriding the span initially set by you**. So try to set the span together.

Comment: Nope, I'm not ovverriding the `AlignmentSpan`. Btw, I tried several combinations but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: How to combine in the same row left and right aligned text in TextView (RadioButton is TextView too). I have found a way in using the ReplacementSpan.

The idea is add one additional symbol (which won't be actual drawn) to the end of text and attach to this symbol your ReplacementSpan where you will be able to do whatever you want - as example drawing additional piece of text in proper place (aligned to right). ReplacementSpan lets define the width of the additional symbol, and this space will be unbreakable.

So, my variant of implementation this idea is can be used like this:

```
RightAlignLastLetterSpan.attach(
                        textView,
                        "right_aligned_piece_of_text",
                        R.style.TextAppereance_of_your_right_aligned_text);
```

It adds a text given as second argument to the *textView* styled with style given as third argument. Added text will be right aligned.

Here is full sources of RightAlignLastLetterSpan:

```
class RightAlignLastLetterSpan extends ReplacementSpan {

    @SuppressWarnings("FieldCanBeLocal") private static boolean DEBUG = false;

    private float textWidth = -1;
    @Nullable private TextAppearanceSpan spanStyle;
    @Nullable private String text;
    @NonNull private TextView tv;

    protected RightAlignLastLetterSpan(@NonNull TextView tv) {this.tv = tv;}

    public static boolean attach(@Nullable TextView tv, @Nullable String text, @StyleRes int resourceTextAppearance) {

        if (tv == null || isEmpty(text)) {
            logWrongArg();
            return false;
        }

        RightAlignLastLetterSpan span = new RightAlignLastLetterSpan(tv);
        span.setSpanStyle(new TextAppearanceSpan(tv.getContext(), resourceTextAppearance));
        span.setText(text);

        SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(new StringBuffer(tv.getText()).append(" _"));
        ss.setSpan(span, ss.length() - 1, ss.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        tv.setText(ss);

        return true;
    }

    public void setSpanStyle(@Nullable TextAppearanceSpan spanStyle) {

        textWidth = -1;
        this.spanStyle = spanStyle;
    }

    public void setText(@Nullable String text) {

        textWidth = -1;
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end, Paint.FontMetricsInt fm) {

        if (textWidth < 0) {
            applyStyle(paint);
            textWidth = isEmpty(this.text) ? 0 : paint.measureText(this.text);
        }

        return Math.round(textWidth);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end, float x, int top, int y, int bottom, Paint paint) {

        if (textWidth == 0 || this.text == null) {
            return;
        }

        int lineCount = tv.getLineCount();
        if (lineCount < 1) {return;}

        Rect lineBounds = new Rect();
        int baseline = tv.getLineBounds(lineCount - 1, lineBounds);
        lineBounds.offset(-tv.getPaddingLeft(), -tv.getPaddingTop());
        baseline -= tv.getPaddingTop();

        if (DEBUG) {
            paint.setColor(Color.argb(100, 100, 255, 100));
            canvas.drawRect(lineBounds, paint);

            paint.setColor(Color.argb(100, 255, 100, 100));
            canvas.drawRect(x, top, x + textWidth, bottom, paint);
        }

        applyStyle(paint);

        canvas.drawText(this.text, lineBounds.right - textWidth, baseline, paint);
    }

    public void applyStyle(Paint paint) {

        if (paint instanceof TextPaint && spanStyle != null) {
            TextPaint tp = (TextPaint) paint;
            spanStyle.updateDrawState(tp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And I have noticed that android:textAllCaps="true" removes other Spannable's